# How does cached text from web pages on laptop browser be displayed in an app on phone, without user initiation?

Tags: linux, networking, google-chrome, android, arch-linux

I was trying to make samba server accessible between my linux host and qemu-kvm run Windows 10 VM. Among the many pages i visited, This ["https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba) was one of them. Once done with work, i closed my Windows 10 VM and started watching a movie on my phone (Android). A bit into the movie, my google translate app pops-up, i opened to see this text "*Set \ Services \ LanmanServer \ Parameters \ Size (set to 3) Alternatively, start Command Prompt in Admin Mode and execute the following:*" which i remembered reading on the page posted earlier on my laptop browser. I am confused as to how, texts from a page i visited be opening up in an app popup?

could someone explain how this happened?

edit: Seems I had copied the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this happened. I have KDE connect installed, both on my android phone and on my Linux laptop, with share clipboard plugin enabled. So when i copy texts on to the clipboard of my laptop, it gets sent to the phone. And any copy "text" action on my phone opens-up the google translate app pop-up on the screen, which is a feature. Hence as soon as the clipboards are synced, google translate pops up.